# Unable to append String NSMutableString - Error

Tags: ios, nsmutablestring

I have the following code

```
NSMutableString *ibmcountryCodeLabel=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
NSMutableString *imobileNumberValue=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
ibmcountryCodeLabel=@"555";
imobileNumberValue=@"333";
NSLog(@"Done1");
[ibmcountryCodeLabel appendString:imobileNumberValue];
NSLog(@"Done2");
```

Though both the string are mutable when I try to append one with another I am getting "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'"

read through all the threads. But not able to find a solution. Kindly help me. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

Here is the problem: this assignment produces a mutable string object:

```
NSMutableString *ibmcountryCodeLabel=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
```

After this assignment, however, the object pointed to by `ibmcountryCodeLabel` is no longer mutable:

```
ibmcountryCodeLabel=@"555";
```

This is because the `@"555"` constant is an immutable subclass of `NSString`. Trying to modify it leads to runtime errors.

Change the code as follows to fix this problem:

```
NSMutableString *ibmcountryCodeLabel=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"555"];
NSMutableString *imobileNumberValue=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"333"];
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In Actual, I am getting the Countrycodelabel from a text box and also the  mobileNumberValue and need to append both. Can you please help me as how to do this??

Comment: @TimothyRajan Sure - simply pass the text from your text boxes to `NSMutableString`'s `stringWithString:` method.

Comment: Another option is to replace `ibmcountryCodeLabel=@"555";` with `[ibmcountryCodeLabel appendString:@"555"];`